# How to get all log information in web API 2 using log4net

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, log4net

I have created a `WEB API`. Now I want to make a log file in which I want to get all the API log information. For this, by using [log4net](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZx1g5oWmMk) I have created a log file.

1. Downloaded it from NuGet.
2. Add `log4net` in `web.config` file

   ```
   <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
   <log4net>
   <root>
     <appender-ref ref ="LogFileAppender"/>
   </root>
   <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
   <param name="File" value="E:\MyLog\LogFile.txt"/>
   <param name="AppendToFile" value ="false"/>
   <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
   <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
   <maximumFileSize value="5MB"/>
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %meesage%newline"/>
   </layout>
   </appender>
   <logger name="ApiLog">
   <level value="DEBUG"/>
   </logger>
   </log4net>
   ```
3. In my `Global.asax.cs` file

   `private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("ApiLog");`

   ```
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
       log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Web.config")));           

   }
   protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
       log.Debug("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
       log.Error("Exception - \n" + ex);

       log.Debug("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
   }
   ```

**Controller**

```
public class MetersController : ApiController
{
    public mdcEntities mdcEntitites = new mdcEntities();

    public HttpResponseMessage GetByMsn(string msn, DateTime dt)
    {
        try
        {
            var dateTime = dt.AddHours(-1);

            var result = mdcEntitites.tj_xhqd.Where(m => (m.zdjh == msn) && (m.sjsj >= dateTime))
                                             .OrderByDescending(o => o.sjsj)
                                             .Select(s => s.sjsj)
                                             .FirstOrDefault();

            DateTime resulted = new DateTime();
            DateTime userSent = new DateTime();

            resulted = Convert.ToDateTime(result);
            userSent = Convert.ToDateTime(dt);

            double diff = Math.Abs((resulted - userSent).TotalMinutes);

            if (diff <= 10)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { data = new { Response = "Yes" } });
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { data = new { Response = "No" } });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I run this API, it did create a log file but it's empty because it will only log for errors.

How can I see my all process log including start and end timeline?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you want log for all method you need to add log at start & end of each method like :

```
    public HttpResponseMessage GetByMsn(string msn, DateTime dt)
    {
            try
            {
               Log.Debug(String.Format("{0} started",  MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;));
               ...
               Log.Debug(String.Format("{0} succeeded",  MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;));
            } 
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
            }
   }
```

**OR**

alternative need **custom action filter** that triggers log after each method like given in below link:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/db2972/trace-web-api-execution-time-using-custom-action-filter/

Comment: Will this be created in a log file ?

Comment: I believe you have already working logging, so just use `private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("ApiLog");` and `log.Debug()` method it will use same log file & append to it

Comment: Initializes `private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("ApiLog");` in my controller class. and then added the methods as per your suggestion and then run my API. But no log file was created.

Comment: With some changes in `web.config` I am able to see a log file. But I can only see the following detail in it 

`2018-07-06 15:23:02,427 [10] DEBUG ApiLog - GetByMsn started eesage
2018-07-06 15:23:14,190 [10] DEBUG ApiLog - GetByMsn succeeded eesage` and it's not enough

Comment: You can add any info pass it as param, or use stack trace

Comment: How can I add it ?